# order without duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
ident_nr|proj_nr|start_time|
----------------------------
05.26.73|0000001|1116936920|
09.56.df|0000002|1213431234|
11.ac.12|0000003|1236485758|
98.er.df|0000001|1287789755|
70.12.5n|0000001|1011245554|
33.dt.vp|0000003|1239125544|
```

And I want a result like this:

```
ident_nr|proj_nr|start_time|
----------------------------
98.er.df|0000001|1287789755|
09.56.df|0000002|1213431234|
33.dt.vp|0000003|1239125544|
```

where proj_nr is in asc order and start time with the max value.

Note: ident_nr is unique and proj_nr could have multiple ident_nr.
Database: MySQL.

Is there an SQL query that could achieve this result?
Thanks

Comment: And which ident_nr do you want to be picked if there are multiple proj_nr?

Comment: @siride: Probably because the problem is poorly explained.

Comment: I am assuming for formatting, when I first read the question it was a giant blob of text. Then ajreal editted the post,

Comment: i only change title -- http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7012028/revisions

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: I think part of answering is helping the users figure out what they are trying to even ask.  Sometimes the problem *is* simply that they are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @siride: I didn't downvote. I was merely speculating as to why the downvote was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.ident_nr, t.proj_nr, t.start_time
    FROM YourTable t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT proj_nr, MAX(start_time) AS MaxTime
                        FROM YourTable
                        GROUP BY proj_nr) q
            ON t.proj_nr = q.proj_nr
                AND t.start_time = q.MaxTime
    ORDER BY t.proj_nr;
```

Comment: @Che: Glad to help. Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it when you are able.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table AS t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT proj_nr, MAX(start_time) AS MaxTime
    FROM table
    GROUP BY proj_nr) AS t2
    ON (t1.proj_nr = t2.proj_nr AND t1.start_time = t2.MaxTime)
```

Your criteria seems to be `MAX(start_time)` in your sample data. If not, please be more detailed in your question about what you want.